# React Konva change zIndex on drag

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

Hey so I have little drag and drop game written in React konva. My draggable piece looks like this (simplified for convenience

```
   return this.props.areas.map((area) => 
        <Image draggable=true 
            {...area.imageProps} 
            onDragStart={() => {...}} 
            onDragEnd={() => {...}} 
            onDragMove={() => {...}}/> )
```

I would like the piece that is currently being dragged to be the one on the highest layer (highest zIndex).

Problem is React-Konva does not support zIndexing, and seems to want you to enforce the zIndexing based on order in the render method.

My solution was to updated the reactState with a currentDragIndex

```
 ...<Image 
    onDragStart = {this.setState({currentDragIndex: area.index})} 
     />
```

Then I try to reorder in the render method. However this causes the drag event to be interrupted.

Anyone have a good solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of some items, the simplest solution is to change that array, by moving the dragging node to the end of the array. In your `render` function you just need to draw items from the array.

```
handleDragStart = e => {
    const id = e.target.name();
    const items = this.state.items.slice();
    const item = items.find(i => i.id === id);
    const index = items.indexOf(item);
    // remove from the list:
    items.splice(index, 1);
    // add to the top
    items.push(item);
    this.setState({
      items
    });
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/11j51wwm3

Comment: The problem with this is that when I change the state, it redraws and interrupts my drag event. So i need to click on the item again to drag it

Comment: It may be interrupted drag event if you don't use `key` property correctly or do not use it at all.

Comment: As you can see there are no issues with the demo I made.

Comment: Okay maybe it is an issue deeper in my code thank you

Comment: Make sure you use `key` in the correct way. That is important.

Comment: Right and what is the correct way of using key. 

I basically set each item id as the key.

Answer (score 4):

You chould just use moveToTop() method

```
 onDragStart={(el) => {el.target.moveToTop();}}
```